# 'symfony console make:migration' doesn't create SQL code

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5

I follow the book *the fast track*, chapter '8.7 Migrer la base de données'.

I have my 2 Entities classes properly generated via `symfony console make:entity` :

```
ls -1 src/Entity/Co*
src/Entity/Comment.php
src/Entity/Conference.php
```

https://pastebin.com/6RJmQTEg
https://pastebin.com/XwZ7csS3

Ran `symfony console make:migration`, get only :

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace DoctrineMigrations;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\Schema;
use Doctrine\Migrations\AbstractMigration;

/**
 * Auto-generated Migration: Please modify to your needs!
 */
final class Version20200322201522 extends AbstractMigration
{
    public function getDescription() : string
    {
        return '';
    }

    public function up(Schema $schema) : void
    {
        // this up() migration is auto-generated, please modify it to your needs

    }

    public function down(Schema $schema) : void
    {
        // this down() migration is auto-generated, please modify it to your needs
        $this->abortIf($this->connection->getDatabasePlatform()->getName() !== 'postgresql', 'Migration can only be executed safely on \'postgresql\'.');

        $this->addSql('CREATE SCHEMA public');
    }
}
```

**Why there's no SQL code generated ?**

My `.env`:

```
APP_ENV=dev
APP_SECRET=xxx
DATABASE_URL=postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/db?serverVersion=11&charset=utf8`
```

The command `symfony run psql` run well; I get psql prompt:

```
[mevatlave:~/sources/guestbook] master* ± symfony run psql
psql (11.7 (Debian 11.7-0+deb10u1))
Type "help" for help.

main=#
```

```
symfony -V
Symfony CLI version v4.13.3 (Thu Mar 19 15:24:08 UTC 2020)
```

```
php bin/console debug:container --env-vars

Symfony Container Environment Variables
=======================================

 -------------- --------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------- 
  Name           Default value   Real value                                                      
 -------------- --------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------- 
  APP_SECRET     n/a             "4ec3efda62f1b3001e78459335893c3f"                              
  DATABASE_URL   n/a             "postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/db?serverVersion=11&charset=utf8"  
 -------------- --------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------- 

 // Note real values might be different between web and CLI.
```

Never edited Symfony config :

```
cat config/packages/doctrine.yaml
doctrine:
    dbal:
        url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'

        # IMPORTANT: You MUST configure your server version,
        # either here or in the DATABASE_URL env var (see .env file)
        #server_version: '5.7'
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
        auto_mapping: true
        mappings:
            App:
                is_bundle: false
                type: annotation
                dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                prefix: 'App\Entity'
                alias: App
```

Comment: Do you need bin/console doctrine:schema:update ? Because if you want use migration you don't use this command.

Comment: I (re)started the project from scratch. I don't use RANDOM commands/code, but follow the book Symfony5 - 'the fast track' _step by step_

Comment: Maybe because your Symfony version is v4.13.3 and you are using the Symfony 5 book?

Comment: Wow, so why the doc ask us to run `wget https://get.symfony.com/cli/installer -O - | bash` which is Symfony 4???

Comment: I was just asking, it's probably ok then. Just trying to figure it out

Comment: No, after asking on slack, the binary version have **nothing to do** with the Symfony version, not the issue

Comment: Is your config for doctrine mapping correct? Something like https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html#custom-mapping-entities-in-a-bundle . And make sure the type is set to "annotation", not xml

Comment: Never edited this config file, added config to original POST

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, found a bug in the book, the DSN is wrong :

`DATABASE_URL=postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/db?serverVersion=11&charset=utf8`

Now : `DATABASE_URL=postgresql://main:main@127.0.0.1:5432/db?serverVersion=11&charset=utf8`

Lack of username/password. Now symfony `console make:migration` works well

Comment: Well done for finding it. Could you get a bug reported on the documentation project?

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing your cache first.

Otherwise try this:
You need doctrine:migrations:diff. That will generate a new migration pre-filled with the SQL that you  would get from a doctrine:schema:update

So:

```
bin/console doctrine:migrations:diff
OR
bin/console d:m:d
```

Then you go check the newly created file and if all is ok you execute it with:

```
// (to be 100% sure take a backup of your database before doing:)

bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate
OR
bin/console d:m:m
```

If you then want to go back because you made a mistake or whatever

```
// Replace 20190215095613 with your migration number!
bin/console doctrine:migrations:execute --down 20190215095613
```

- Then you can modify the migration and again execute "bin/console d:m:m"
- Or throw away the migration and start over with "bin/console d:m:d"

Comment: There's no cache, I (re)started the project from scratch. I don't use RANDOM commands/code, but follow the book Symfony5 - 'the fast track' _step by step_